# Topology not creating from OSM wizard (Browser) (file:///home/rehan/sumo-0.32.0/tools/webWizard/index.html)

Tags: ns2

```
rehan@rehan-Y11C:~/sumo-0.32.0/tools$ python osmWebWizard.py Building scenario in '/home/rehan/sumo-0.32.0/tools/2019-11-15-12-29-32'
Downloading map data
200 OK
Converting map data
Usage: osmWebWizard.py [options]

osmWebWizard.py: error: typemap file "/home/sumo-0.32.0/sumo/data/typemap/osmPolyconvert.typ.xml" not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "osmWebWizard.py", line 379, in build
    builder.build()
  File "osmWebWizard.py", line 187, in build
    osmBuild.build(options)
  File "/home/rehan/sumo-0.32.0/tools/osmBuild.py", line 68, in build
    optParser.error('typemap file "%s" not found' % options.typemap)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1584, in error
    self.exit(2, "%s: error: %s\n" % (self.get_prog_name(), msg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1574, in exit
    sys.exit(status)
SystemExit: 2

Recovering
Recovering
Recovering
```

Comment: As your error output says : `... sumo/data/typemap/osmPolyconvert.typ.xml" not found`. ... Seems to be a PATH problem ... or : The file osmPolyconvert.typ.xml is actually not in that location.